# Program to compute a polynomial equation

Tags: c

I need to wap  which asks user for input  of a natural num . - end

The entered number needs to be greater than 1 . If the condition is not meet , show the user message  " end needs to be greater than 1 "  and then ask him again for the input using a loop . After  the correct input 
value ,  calculate for every number between 1 and variable end   , the following equations.

Im unable to get correct output

```
x^4-2x^2+1-(x+1)^2          
x(x-2)(x+1)^2
```

the  output should be  as follows

```
x expression 1  expression 2 
 1  -4         -4
 2   0          0
 3   48         48 
     ...**
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main (){
int v , x , end  ;

do {printf( "enter a natural number  ");

scanf  (  "%d", &end);
if  ( end <1 ){

printf ( " entered number needs to be greater than 1  ");
scanf  (  "%d", &end); }
}   while ( end<=1);  
 int arr [end];
 int m ;
 for(m=3 ;  m<x ; m++ ) {

 for (x=1 ; x<end ; x++)  

  v= pow(x,4)- 2*(x,2)+1-((x+1),2);      
  printf (" %d", v   );  


   printf ( "%d",m );
   printf ("\n");

   }}
```

Comment: `^` is the bitwise-XOR operator.  It does _not_ perform exponentiation.

Comment: regarding: `#include <conio.h>`  The header file: `conio.h` is a nonstandard header, only found on windows.  Please make it a habit of using the standard IO function rather than the 'learner' functions in `conio.h`

Comment: regarding: `main (){`  There are only two valid signatures for the `main()` function.  (regardless of what visual studio allows) They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  Any modern compiler (which visual studio is not) will output a warning message about this problem

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding;  1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '};'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) please follow the axion: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  Note: consider a closing brace '}'. as a separate statement.

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf ( "%d" , &end);`  The `scanf()` family of functions returns the number of successful input conversions.  Always check that returned number to assure the operation was successful.  I.E. `if( scanf ( "%d" , &end) != 1 ) { // handle error }`

Comment: regarding: `printf ( " entered number needs to be greater than 1  ")`  per the statement: `while ( end<1);`  This is not true.  Rather any number >=1 will end the loop

Comment: When the code first reaches `for(m=3 ;  m<x ; m++ ) {`, `x` has not yet been assigned a value.